# Search row for array match of a specific word, and return the dates from column A that match

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

**Objective:**

- Looking up Class ID (ignoring anything past the **), and return corresponding date in (B2:B).
- Then Looking up Class Event, and return the corresponding date in (C2:C).

*I have tried combinations of HLookup, VLookup, Index & Match, and Query, but cannot seem to get it to work correctly.*

**My Sheet:**

```
Column |      A       |        B?       |          C?        |     D      |      E      |      F      |
Row1   | [Class ID's] | [Class ID Date] | [Class Event Date] |  [Dates]   |   [Name1]   |   [Name2]   |
Row2   |  Class ID1   |    01/02/2021   |     01/04/2021     | 01/01/2021 |             | Class ID3** |
Row3   |  Class ID2   |    01/08/2021   |     01/09/2021     | 01/02/2021 | Class ID1** |             |
Row4   |  Class ID3   |    01/01/2021   |     01/07/2021     | 01/03/2021 |             | Class ID4** |
Row5   |  Class ID4   |    01/03/2021   |     01/09/2021     | 01/04/2021 | Class Event |             |
Row6   |  Class ID5   | * Formula #1 *  |   * Formula #2 *   | 01/05/2021 |             |             |
Row7   |  Class ID6   |                 |                    | 01/06/2021 |             |             |
Row8   |  Class ID7   |                 |                    | 01/07/2021 |             | Class Event |
Row9   |  Class ID8   |                 |                    | 01/08/2021 | Class ID2** |             |
Row10  |  Class ID9   |                 |                    | 01/09/2021 | Class Event | Class Event |
Row11  |  Class ID10  |                 |                    | 01/10/2021 |             |             |
```

**Formula #1 (Column: B)**

- Find the class ID, and returning the dates into range: B2:B (Working, but not efficient)
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D,MATCH($A2,E$2:E,0)),INDEX($D$2:$D,MATCH($A2,F$2:F,0)))`
  ...and so on, for each column (There are 60 columns).

**Formula #2 (Column: C)**

- Find class ID, search column, find first instance of "Class Event", return date into range: C2:C 
  `="I have absolutely no clue for this one"`

**Is this even possible in Google Sheets?**
*I can use excel if needed (but preferably not as this sheet pulls data from another Google Sheet)*

Comment: The most effective and efficient way to get help here is to share a link to a sample spreadsheet with data that represents your rea-world data and setup, being sure to set the link's Share permissions to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." A picture or typed data allows us to see part of the data and issue, but it does not allow for us to be able to work on it, test solutions, etc. (to even start would require that we manually enter your data into our own sheet, which isn't usually feasible). If you share a link, please manually enter the results you'd like to see with explanations.

Comment: 60 columns of what?

Comment: @ErikTyler Great tip! I will do that shortly!

Comment: @player0 Column E:BN contain data in the same type of format (created by someone else). The only differences are that the Class ID's and Class Events are on different rows. - My goal is to compile all that data from E:BN within A:C instead which is far easier to read.

Comment: If you don't really want an Excel answer, it's easier to just not include that tag. Removed it (again).

Comment: answer updated for 60 columns...

Answer (score 2):

C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {F2:F, E2:E; G2:G, E2:E}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

D2:

as for now, how you stated the dataset, there is nothing to pair events with specific IDs - it would be possible if you would have

```
Class ID4 Event
```

instead of just

```
Class Event
```

---

### update 1:

C2 for 60 columns would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(F2:BN="",,F2:BN&"×"&E2:E)), "×"), 2, 0)))
```

### update 2:

try in D2 (but it will work only if class event will follow after each id class)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)="",,
 TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(E2:E))), "×"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 is not null", 0), {
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)="",,
 TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(E2:E))), "×"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 is not null", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0); ""}}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness! You are a wizard! That is without a doubt the most condensed formula to search all the columns! THANK YOU!

Comment: As for D2, I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately the original data is from another sheet which I only have view access too. I have no idea why they used this horrible method of formatting (E:BN). That's why I'm trying to re-format it into something easier to read (A:C).

Comment: @JamesReed68 for D2... is it safe to say that after each Class ID immediately follows one Class Event?

Comment: 95% of the time its safe to say after a class ID, there is a Class Event. I would be very happy to  even have that type of accuracy, and still have the remining 5% a mystery...unless there is some way to apply logic to this undefined variable.

Comment: Wow! Extremely impressive. That does the trick for the 95% perfectly. As for the remaining 5%, looking at your formula, it pulls the next non Null cell. Is there a way to add an if condition such as =IF(x=(LEFT(x,5)="Class"),select Col2 where Col2 is not null) so it can find the correct date?

Comment: Tried this, but does not want to work. "select Col1 where Col2 is not null and not &"×"& contains 'Class' " ----  "select Col2 where Col2 is not null and not &"×"& contains 'Class' "

Comment: Update to previous reply: As for the cells labeled "Class Event", they are now labeled "Event" to keep things more unique.  So is there a way to add an extra condition to the query to skip: 1) is not null 2) not contains 'Class'? Or another way?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, {
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)="",,
 TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(E2:E))), "×"), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 contains 'Event'", 0), {
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)="",,
 TRANSPOSE(F2:BN)&"×"&TRANSPOSE(E2:E))), "×"), 
 "select Col2 where Col2 contains 'Event'", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0); ""}}, 2, 0)))`